# Setup Spring method security defaulting to authenticated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to get Spring Boot working with the following specifications:

- Access control should be included in each controller class, not in a central "http.antMatcher(.." statement.
- If a programmer doesn't include access control detail in a controller method it should default to "any authenticated user"
- It should be possible to denote some methods as "public", available to unauthenticated users.

Here is my sample Controller:

```java
@Controller
public class ExampleController {

  // this should be available for everyone
  @PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
  @RequestMapping("/")
  @ResponseBody
  public String home() {
    return "Welcome home!";
  }

  // available to every authenticated user
  @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
  @RequestMapping("hello")
  @ResponseBody
  public String hello() {
    return "world";
  }

  // here we forgot to add Preautorize annotation
  // It should default to Authenticated or not available at all
  @RequestMapping("careless")
  @ResponseBody
  public String careless() {
    return "programmer";
  }

  // this should be available for everyone too
  @PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
  @RequestMapping("free")
  @ResponseBody
  public String free() {
    return "willy";
  }  

}
```

I've tried many distinct configurations, none of them works as expected.

Here are the most relevant, with a comparative summary table at the end.

**Solution 1 - No override**
Create a class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter without override anything and setup EnableGlobalMethodSecurity.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

It doesn't work, Springs requires login for everything.

**Solution 2 - Override with empty method**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {}  
}
```

It doesn't work, because Spring defaults to "public" if method is not annotated.

**Solution 3 - configure override**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**")  
    .authorizeRequests()  
    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()  
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().formLogin(); 
  }  
}
```

It doesn't work, Spring doesn't allow to make a method public with "permitAll" annotation.

In summary:

```
|          | Wanted     | Sol-1 no | Sol-2 empty | Sol-3 config. |
|          | Behavior   | override | override    | override      |
|----------|------------|----------|-------------|---------------|
| home     |  public    |  login   |  public     | public        |
| hello    |  login     |  login   |  login      | login         |
| careless |  login     |  login   |  public     | login         |
| free     |  public    |  login   |  public     | login         |
```

Also it would be acceptable if the not annotated method (careless) is not available for anyone.

How can I get the wanted behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure you can achieve what you want, without separating the public and private endpoints to different sub URL-s (eg.: /public/** which doesn't have web security on it, and everything else, that require authentication). The HttpSecurity antmatcher that you define in your SecurityConfig applies to the web request filter so that will always run first. If the request passes through this, the method level security comes into action and checks the permission.
Here's a good article about this:
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/20/spring-preauthorize

Comment: thanks @gybandi , using a "/public/..." url for not secured endpoints will do the trick.